# SQL Server 2017 CDC: 60 second polling time

Tags: sql-server, cdc

SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1000.169)
2 Tables with CDC
Problem:

- The CDC capture runs only every 60 seconds - but as you can see on the image - pollinginterval is 5 (seconds?)
- Its a huge server - Task manager shows no activity - SQL Activity monitor also
- The database / tables are created, 13875 records are inserted (and then nothing its done - just waiting for CDC to catch up - the whole SQL Server is on idle) - no changes to capture job
- SQL Server Agent has not warnings / errors in log

Expected behaviour: Every 5 seconds 5000 transactions (500 (trans) * 10 (scans)) should be commited.

Any idea?

EDIT: If i call sys.sp_cdc_scan manually - 5000 transaction are commited to CDC table. So why the hell does it not work with the agent?!

[image]

Comment: Can you state exactly what the problem is.

Comment: First bullet: Only every 60 seconds 500 trans are committed. Expected: Every 5 seconds at least 500 trans are commited (I expected 500 * 10 because of scan - but ok).

Comment: How are those 13875 records inserted? All in one transaction? 13875 transactions? Somewhere in between?

Comment: 13875 transactions. 1 record = 1 trans. Its very confusing - if i call "sys.sp_cdc_scan" it commits several thound records (4000-5000) to the _CT table. I deleted the DB, i restarted everything - i dont know whats wrong :-S With Only 500 records per minute I cant use it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing CU13 solved the problem - works now ...